# Laravel delay queue job dispatch after x hour minutes second

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have set my laravel timezone to 'Asia/Kolkata' which is 5:30 hrs ahead of GMT.
When i am dispatching job, job is starting after 5:30 hours dispatching which should as all customers are from same timezone. Also, it is showing available at 5:30 hrs ahead. Like when i am setting it to start at 4:30 when current time is 3:30, job delay is taking 5:30 hrs ahead and starting at 10:00.

I have tried setting Linux,laravel timezone, php artisan config:cache, still it is taking 5:30 hrs ahead.

My code:

```
$diff = strtotime($start_time) - strtotime($current_datetime);
        $job_delay_hour = date("H", $diff);
        $job_delay_minute = date("i", $diff);
        $job_delay_second = date("s", $diff);

$job_id = $this->dispatch(($job)
            ->onQueue('splitter')
            ->delay(now()->addHour($job_delay_hour)->addMinutes($job_delay_minute)->addSeconds($job_delay_second)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed it

```
$job_id = $this->dispatch(($job)
        ->onQueue('splitter')->delay($diff);
```

Comment: It could be nice to add an explanation with the code sample

Answer (score 5):

You can use Carbon instance to get specific date. Complete example regarding to Laravel v6.x. Should be work on old versions too:

```php
public function store() {
    // some stuff

    // after 10 minutes
    $on = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);        

    dispatch(new \App\Jobs\SomeJob(...$someVariables))->delay($on);
}
```

Comment: `now()` helper can be used instead of `\Carbon\Carbon::now()`